# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'sdate' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union-all

I got this error in my Query, do you have any idea how can I put the `sdate` in the 2 layer subquery?

```
select
at.startDate as sdate, at.dau as DAU,
(
select count(distinct d.uid) from
 (select ses.uid from dsession as ses where ses.startDate = sdate group by ses.uid
  union all
  select res.uid from rsession as res where res.startDate = sdate group by res.uid) as te
) as MAU, (SELECT DAU/MAU) as AVG
from
attendance as at
```

it works if I query alone the subquery but when I merge it to the main query, the `sdate` got unknown. any idea?

I tried to replace `sdate` on `where` as `at.startDate` but still got unknown `at.startDate` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the selects in the main select clause I created a subquery to join against so that startDate could be checked

```
SELECT at.startDate AS sdate, at.dau AS DAU, (DAU/MAU.cnt) as AVG
FROM attendance AS at
JOIN (SELECT startdate, count(distinct uid) as cnt
      FROM (SELECT uid, startdate FROM dsession
            UNION ALL
            SELECT uid, startdate FROM rsession) as ua
      GROUP BY startdate
     ) as MAU ON MAU.startdate = at.startdate
```

Hopefully I didn't mess anything up when restructuring the query :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in the `where` clause.  Just use the original column name:

```
where at.startDate between @startDate and @endDate
```

The alias *is* accepted in the `order by`, so that does not have to change.

Comment: I swear I almost saw your answer pop up _before_ the question finished loading +1.

Comment: The subquery is nested twice. `at` is unknown in that scope.